# Typing G+X or R+X is not working. Instead is asking me if I want to delete

Tags: modeling, shortcut

When I hit <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> I'm expecting movement along the $X$ axis by an amount I type in.

Similarly, I'd expect <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>$90$ to rotate the selected object(s) about the $X$-axis $90$°. Instead, the $X$ is taken as a delete command and I get a dialog box asking if OK to delete.

Is this a change in Blender or am I doing something wrong? I'd really like to be able to type <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and a number or <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> and a number.

Comment: An individual X is to delete. but R+X is to rotate on x, G+X is to grab on x, S+X is to scale on X. I can only ask you to make sure whether you are doing it correctly, making sure keyboard is working; Otherwise I don't know how to solve it because this seems extremely weird and had never happened to me. Just to run a test, if you just hit R, are you rotating the object? keep in the state of rotation, hit X, does it help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gertsmann. That is exactly what I'm doing G, then X but it deletes from the X. When I hit the G it puts the gizmo about the object, but when I hit X next it deletes the object. I just upgraded from 2.8 to 2.81a hoping it would fix the issue, but it does not.

Comment: What do you mean by delete from X? What system are you working with? Are you using the official build? In the worse case, can you try goes to file, default, load factory setting to see if things have been fixed?

Comment: Just did file |default | load factory settings and it works as expected again. Thanks!

Comment: Great, You may want to save startup after load factory setting. because load setting only works for the current file.

Comment: Did that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a special keyboard layout in your system? What OS? Do other keyboard shortcut fail?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you inadvertently deleted the shortcut in the keymaps, or you set it to something else, overriding it. Clicking on *Restore* in the keymaps in the preferences should clear the modification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If I hit <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>, it asks me if I want to delete the object instead of locking X axis. Can't change angle by numbers with <kbd>R</kbd> either.

Solved:
You need to hold the mouse button pressed while rotating/moving, and then you can press x/y/z and numeric values. Hope it helped.

Comment: Good it works, but this shouldn't be necessary.. OP's behaviour is beginning to look like a bug?

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it is misleading. It is not necessary to hold the mouse button pressed to lock transforms to X axis. This is a workaround of other unresolved issue, maybe a bug, but not something that is supposed to happen.

Comment: Hello Gabriel :). If you read the comments, the OP solved it by loading factory settings. If it that doesn't work for you, please consider asking a New question :).

Comment: Got it guys. Sorry if it wasn't super correct. It's the work around that worked for me, but I see there's better simpler ways.